# source of the world being created with lashon hakodesh

Tags: sources-mekorot, hebrew, creation

Where does the Mizrachi say (with exact wording) that the world was created with lashon hakodesh?

quoted from Artscroll (schottenstein edition) parshas noach 11:1-9

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please tell us why you think that the Mizrahi says this. This can help us find the answer. Consider also reading this short Beginners' Guide to the site: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites.

Comment: Are you by any chance the same user as: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13898/user13898? If so, the moderators can merge your accounts.

Comment: And again, its best to mention that this is the Stone ed. Humash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He writes this in his commentary to Parshat Noah (11:1 s.v. safah ahat):

> (א) שפה אחת לשון הקדש. כדמשמע מקרא ד"לזאת יקרא אשה כי מאיש לוקחה זאת" (ב, כג), כדאיתא בבראשית רבה (בראשית רבה יח, ו): "שמעת מימיך גיני - גיניאה, אתרופו - אתרופיאה, גברא - גברתא", אין שֵׁם האשה נגזר משם האיש בשום לשון חוץ מלשון הקדש, **וכך פירש רש"י ז"ל שָׁם: "לשון נופל על הלשון, מכאן שנברא העולם בלשון הקדש".** ומאחר שהלשון ההוא לא נשתנה עד זמן דור הפלגה שנחלקו הלשונות, יחוייב שתהיה השפה ההיא לשון הקדש בהכרח.

Comment: thanks!!! and yes, how do i merge the accounts?

Comment: The moderators can do it. I have flagged your comment for moderator attention. Hopefully they should help you out soon enough...

Comment: @mevaqesh and LMF, as far as I understand, it's SO staff, not mods, who can help with duplicate accounts. See [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions.

Comment: @LittleMissFabulous, IsaacMoses is quite right: we site moderators can't help you, sorry.